# How do I combine multiple java buttons into a pile on the taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, java, taskbar

Does any one know how to have open java windows stack in the windows taskbar?

I'm running a few (20) java apps and they don't combine therefore taking up loads of room on my task bar.

Taskbar properties for "Taskbar buttons" is set to "Always combine, hide labels", and I've tried messing with it, then messing with it again just in case.

I'm running them via a batch script, and they all have different titles (presumably the issue) but are all java.exes (I have tried running them with the same title but no luck).

e.g.
start /MIN %NAME% "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Xmx512m -Djava.library.path=./win32 -jar %NAME%.jar

I'm sure I've got this to work before but I had an explorer crash recently and I'm blaming that for this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `isHostApp` registry setting from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\java.exe`

Obviously be very careful with registry settings. Presumably this was reinstated following a Java install and only picked up after an Explorer restart.

All credit to this post:
http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/84690-taskbar-grouping-appid-not-working.html