# How do I combine multiple java (OpenJDK) buttons into a pile on the taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-registry, java, taskbar

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/465002/how-do-i-combine-multiple-java-buttons-into-a-pile-on-the-taskbar#465248) for Oracle's Java runtime. But I am running [ojdkbuild (OpenJDK)](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild) which doesn't seem to create the same registry entries.

I have done a search for "isHostApp" & "java.exe" within the registry & have not yet found anything. The ojdkbuild installer does create some entries in [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/wiki/InstallerEnvironment), but does not appear to be what I am looking for.

I would have just commented on the above question, but I do not have 50 reputation yet.

**Edit:** I found the following keys & removed "JAVA.EXE" & "JAVAW.EXE" from them but didn't make a difference:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileAssociation\HostApps
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileAssociation\HostApps